# Latex: Page number suppressing when a figure covers the whole page

Tags: latex, formatting, figure

I want to suppress page number in a page where a figure covers the whole page.

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.95\textheight]{853}}
    \caption{Whole Model Part 1}
    \label{fig:wholemodel}
\end{figure}
```

I use the command `\thispagestyle{empty}` as suggested. But this command doesn't work where a figure covers the whole page. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Have you tried putting it *inside* the figure environment? Don't know if it works at all.

Comment: Yes, I tried all the places. It didn't make any change.

Comment: I put \newpage and \pagebreak before \thispagestyle, but this doesn't make any difference either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you need the floatpag package.
In preamble put:

```
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{empty}
```

\thisfloatpagestyle{} inside a figure/table environment will alter that floatpage's style.
Hope that works!

PS: the help shown by "$ texdoc floatpag" appears to be in Polish. Look at the .sty file for usage in English. [floatpag.sty on CTAN](ftp://cam.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sttools/floatpag.sty)